# Docker Mysql container

Tags: docker

i have two containers,

container 1 web application
container 2 mysql
am using normal docker file for web application configuration.
when i try to access db connection using web application.
the connection is not working.what will be the issue?
and even i can't ping mysql container ip address, that ip is not reachable why?
but, the db connection is working in local server.
any ideas, will be very helpful.

i want to use two containers
1 is webapplication and another one is mysql
i should make the db connection through mysql container for web application container.
please share you ideas and suggestions

Comment: "the connection is not working" - sounds like you've misconfigured something. But as you haven't shared any details about your Docker setup, nor about how you use it, it's impossible to tell you why this is going wrong

Comment: If you are using localhost to set the connection url, change it to the service name. Anyway, as   @NicoHaase says, you should share your setup